# Working with CCSpriteBatchNode without using .plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am currently working on a simple game that uses animation under iOS environment.I have a single .png file 
[image]
which contains all the frames related to the animation altogether. I got some queries:

1. Is it possible to directly use this image to extract the individual frame images which are required to create the CCSpriteBatchNode?
2. Is there any  way to use this single image directly to create the animation without using the .plist file?
3. Or I have to use TexturePacker like software to create the .png and .plist like file using the individual  frame images of animation?

i)

[image]

ii)
[image](using these)

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2):

1 & 2: Yes. Provided that the sprite frames are all of the same size this is rather trivial. Just offset the texture rect used for CCSprite by the width of each frame. You can create CCSpriteFrame objects manually, and then call addSpriteFrame:name: on CCSpriteFrameCache to cache and index them by name - if you need that.

You can then use the texture to initialize a batch node if you have multiple characters using this animation. If this is your player animation (ie only one sprite using the texture) you can skip creating the sprite batch node since it's just one sprite displaying one of several frames of the same texture at any given time.

3: TexturePacker will certainly make your life a lot easier. You don't have to write extra code (that could contain bugs) to process the animation frames, and TP can pack the images more tightly, eliminating transparent areas and duplicate frames.

Comment: +1 for clarifying the batch node's usefulness with regards to animations.

Answer (score 0):

You better split this image using any [image splitting  online tool](http://imagesplitter.net/) and extract individual images. Then Use [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/) to generate plist data file and the texture image file which CCSpriteBatchNode understands.